# Flask UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, flask

Error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 24: ordinal not in range(128)

So basically I have a Flask app where users fill a sign up form and it renders a new page.

Here's the code:

```
render_template('signUpSuccess.html', password="You should know, right? ")
```

It's not a serious project just a practice app I'm creating since I'm learning Python.  I'm positive it's because of the emoji. I've tried other SO questions but just can't figure it out. I know the emoji is not necessary but It'd be nice to know how I can fix this in the future.

Comment: Are you using Python2 or Python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing a `unicode` object, not a `str` into `render_template()`, like so:

```
render_template('signUpSuccess.html', password=u"You should know, right? ")
```

Sample program:

```
# coding: utf-8
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def root():
    return render_template('signUpSuccess.html', password=u"You should know, right? ")

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

template:

```
<html>password: {{ password }}</html>
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should decode that string. Try this:

```
the_password = "You should know, right? "
the_password = the_password.decode('utf-8')

render_template('signUpSuccess.html', password=the_password)
```