# Invalid unicode strings in Flask, when using parameters in routes

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I use Flask to run a RESTful service and have discovered, that Unicode characters are not being passed correctly, when values are passed as parameters.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

...

@app.route('/search/<query>')
def Search(query):
    result = { "result": query }
    return jsonify(result), 200
```

When I call the service using a REST client with URL ...

```
http://localhost/search/zürich
```

... the output looks like this:

```
{
    "result": "z\ufffdrich"
}
```

When hard coding the query string like this:

```
@app.route('/search/<query>')
def Search(query):
    result = { "result": "Zürich" }
    return jsonify(result), 200
```

... the output is correctly encoded:

```
{
    "result": "Zürich"
}
```

So I digged in the Flask [config options](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/#builtin-configuration-values) settings and have set the options parameter 'JSON_AS_ASCII' to false.

> By default Flask serialize object to ascii-encoded JSON. If this is set to False Flask will not encode to ASCII and output strings as-is and return unicode strings. jsonify will automatically encode it in utf-8 then for transport for instance.

Is that a bug in Flask or did I miss anything in the Flask configuration setting?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by urlencoding the query string. So instead of http://localhost/search/zürich I called the url as this: http://localhost/search/Z%C3%BCrich. That resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This documentation means that if

```
app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False
```

The output will be in unicode.

So it should be set to `True` to get the output in ASCII, which is what you want.

Comment: That is exactly what I did in the Flask configuration. However it does not resolve the issue of handling unicode strings as function parameters correctly. Even the console output shows an incorrect encoding: 127.0.0.1 - - [13/Mar/2018 10:15:26] "GET /search/Z�rich HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by urlencoding the query string. So instead of http://localhost/search/zürich I called the url as this: http://localhost/search/Z%C3%BCrich. That resolved the issue.

Comment: Sure, that's a workaround. You could get the desired result by sending the query in Unicode, this may help: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38494772/flask-unicodedecodeerror)

Comment: I was working on my routes and out of curiosity tested this scenario with "GET /subscribe/zürich@test.com" 200 and I was getting the response back as expected. I am using `Response(json.dumps({'result:data'})`. The `data` variable contains the query response.